# How to make a normally distributed variable depend on entries and time in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, simulation, panel

I'm trying to generate a dataset of cross sectional time series to estimate uses of different models.
In this dataset, I have a ID variable and time variable. I'm trying to add a normally distributed variable that depends on the two identifications. In other words, how do I create a variable that recongizes both ID and time in R?
If my question appears uncertain, feel free to ask any questions.
Thanks in advance.

```
df2 <- read.table(
text =
"Year,ID,H,
1,1,N(2.3),
2,1,N(2.3),
3,1,N(2.3),
1,2,N(0.1),
2,2,N(0.1),
3,2,N(0.1),
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: What does the time variable look like? Could you maybe post 5 rows of ID, time and output you would expect?

Comment: The time-variable is 1...n, with large n.

Comment: The ID and time are of balanced panel data form, that is every ID is observed at at all time. What I'm trying to generate is a variable that is normally distributed but recongizes different IDs. i.e. ID1 doesnt have same mean and variance as ID2 and so forth.

Comment: Potentially changing over time too, but I think that's irrelevant for normal distribution?

Comment: Is the data in long format— meaning one ID column and one time column?

Comment: Correct. I'm adding an example in the original question now.

Comment: In the data frame, H is distribution and N(2.3) is N(2,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data in the dataframe `df` looks like

| ID | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

you can generate a variable `y` that depends on ID and time as the sum of two random normal distributions (yielding another normal distribution) that depend on `ID` and `time` respectively:

```
set.seed(42)


df = data.frame(
  ID   = rep(1:4,   each=3),
  time = rep(1:3,   times=4)
)

df$y = rnorm(nrow(df), mean=df$ID,   sd=1+0.1*df$ID) + 
       rnorm(nrow(df), mean=df$time, sd=0.05*df$time)

# Output:
   ID time         y
1   1    1  3.438611
2   1    2  2.350953
3   1    3  4.379443
4   1    4  5.823339
5   2    1  3.470909
6   2    2  3.607005
7   2    3  6.447756
8   2    4  6.150432
9   3    1  6.608619
10  3    2  4.740341
11  3    3  7.670543
12  3    4 10.215574
```

Note that the underlying normal distributions depend on both `ID` and `time`. That is in contrast to your example table above where it looks like it solely depends on `ID` -- namely resulting in a single normal distribution per ID that is independent of the time variable.